# Generation of a simple title

Tags: titles, rules

How can i get the following result using a fixed-width right rule and a line-filling left rule ?

[image: Not numbered chapter title]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Just taking the definitions from `article.cls` and adding a rule:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\xhrulefill \normalfont\Large\bfseries\zz{2cm}}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\xhrulefill\normalfont\large\bfseries\zz{1.5cm}}}


\newcommand\zz[2]{\mbox{ #2 \makebox[#1]{\xhrulefill}}}
\newcommand\xhrulefill{\noindent\leaders\vrule height5pt depth -4pt \hskip 0pt plus 1fill}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{oops}
\subsection{ahhh}
hello
\section{hoops}
\subsection{hahhh}
goodbye
\end{document}
```

Comment: For better results in the subsection title, the `height` and `depth` for the `\vrule` ought to be font dependent (say `.8ex` and `1pt-.8ex`), in which case the first \xhrulefill would have to be moved to after the font selection, preferably inside the definition of `\zz`.

Comment: @Dan yes, I decided to add the subsection after I'd written the original code as the example looked a bit thin otherwise:-) (edit if you wish:-)