# Can I use patchcmd to modify definitions in book.cls?

Tags: indentation, sections-paragraphs, patching

Below are the commands for `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` in `book.cls`.

```
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%        
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}% 
                                       {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                       {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
```

I want subparagraph numbers to be at the left margin, and I want the first paragraph after the titles to be unindented. I rely on a description of the syntax for `\@startsection` [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/nmtthesis/old/annotated/at.startsection.html). An approach which works, but which I hope not to resort to in the long run, is to modify the definitions directly in `book.cls`, say, to:

```
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%        
                                    {-3.25ex \@plus-1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}% 
                                       {-3.25ex \@plus-1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                       {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
```

Could the same changes be made on a temporary basis, without tinkering with `book.cls`, using `patchcmd` ?

Below is pasted the requisite MWE which shows or doesn't show the effect, depending on whether I have modified `book.cls`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}\lipsum[2]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\lipsum[2]
\paragraph{A paragraph}\lipsum[2]
\subparagraph{A subparagraph}\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can just make those redefinitions in your file, just surround them between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. ***Never*** modify an official class file, you'll soon regret having done it.

Comment: @egreg thanks. the same idea occurred to me just after having typed up the question!

Comment: And use `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand`.

Comment: don't even think of editing book.cls directly it will lead to all sorts of pain (and depending how you do it may be contrary to the licence under which latex is distributed). You can use a patch command or you can simply put the definitions you need in your preamble (changing `\newcommand` to `\renewcommand`) see for example the redefinition here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145920/generation-of-a-simple-title/145923#145923

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specific to your question: "Can I use patchcmd to modify definitions in `book.cls`?" The answer is yes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,etoolbox}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}\lipsum[2]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\lipsum[2]
\paragraph{A paragraph}\lipsum[2]
\subparagraph{A subparagraph}\lipsum[2]

% Update \subparagraph from book.cls
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\subparagraph}{\parindent}{\z@}{}{}% Remove indent
\patchcmd{\subparagraph}{3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}{-3.25ex \@plus-1ex \@minus -.2ex}{}{}% Update spacing/indent
\patchcmd{\subparagraph}{-1em}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}{}{}% Update display/hang
\makeatother

\subparagraph{A subparagraph}\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Since you're interested in updated "3 searches" in `\subparagraph`, all of which are different, 3 separate `\patchcmd`s are required since the replacement works on pattern matching (it's just simpler that way, although it can be achieved using only one). Depending on your preference, it might be easier to just use `\renewcommand`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}% 
                                         {-3.25ex \@plus-1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                         {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                         {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

The above provides a contextual update of *entire* structure of `\subparagraph`, and is more clear.