# What is the bibliographystyle which displays the bibliography like amsart

Tags: bibliographies, books, amsart

I like the way `amsart` displays the bibliography. It is very compact and shows many references in a single page. I would like to use this style for the style `book`. If I change book to amsart in the below code, I have the desired output, but the problem is that because of the particularity of my document I should use the style `book` (and neither amsbook nor amsart).

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\bibliography{my_bibtex}
\bibliographystyle{amsplain} 
\cite{1}, \cite{2}, \cite{3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Obviously it is the same bibliographystyle (`amsplain`). But in the `amsart` class the section headers are different, the font size in the `thebibliography` environment is set to `\footnotesize` and the vertical spacing is decreased. So you would have to write your own `thebibliography` environment to get the desired output.

Comment: the only significant difference i see is the resetting of the font size.  if you can patch in `\footnotesize` in the `thebibliography` definition of `book.cls`, just before the `\list`, you should be almost there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the really significant difference is in the font size.
`amsart` uses `\footnotesize`.

you can patch the definition in `book.cls` using `\patchcmd`.  insert the
command `\footnotsize` just before the `\list` in the definition of
`thebibliography`.

an example of using `\patchcmd` with the `book` class (although for a different
situation) is given in the question
[Can I use patchcmd to modify definitions in book.cls?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146116/579)